две локалки git для одного аккаунта github
есть основной комп и рабочий ноут
на компе я авторизовался в консоли git bash под своими настоящими данными,  в точности, как в аккаунте github, использовав эти команды:
git config --global user.name "John Doe"
git config --global user.email johndoe@example.com

могу ли я на нотбуке привязать свою же точно ту же самую почту,  но указать другое имя, например "qwe-work-laptop"
то есть аккаунт github один и тот же, но на пк и ноутбуке разные имена

@ralph рекомендую ознакомиться: Нормы поведения

С авторизацией эти команды никак не связаны. Это просто информация, которая записывается в созданные коммиты (как данные об авторе), поэтому туда можно писать что угодно.
Представьте, например, что вы заливаете в свой репозиторий изменения, созданные другим человеком. Автор коммита там будет указан совсем другой, но это не помешает вам их пушнуть.

Согласен с комментариями, что лучше везде использовать одинаковые данные. Как минимум потому, что иначе статистика на гитхабе (кто сколько накоммитил) ломается.

запомнил, спасибо большое!

к моему репозиторию только я доступ имею, так что думаю ничего не засорится

@ralph Попробуйте открыть статистику по коммитам и посмотрите. Скорее всего отобразятся два отдельных "человека".

нет, только один - я

Коммиты вроде по почтовому адресу группируются в статистике.
